# LibCurl CURLOPT_URL not accepting string? C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error, libcurl

So basically what I want to do is use libcurl to fetch slightly different urls, e.g.:

```
http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=*NAMEHERE*
```

What I would like to do is iterate through a vector of names and get each one, e.g.:

```
http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=James
```

Then

```
http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=Andrew
```

And so on.

However, when I try doing this:

```
int foo (){
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode success;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    int m_timeout = 15;

    if ((curl = curl_easy_init()) == NULL) {
        perror("curl_easy_init");
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> names;

    names.push_back("James");
    names.push_back("Andrew");

    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = names.begin(); i != names.end(); ++i){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, long(m_timeout));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=" + *i);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1L);
    }

    if ((success = curl_easy_perform(curl)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "curl_easy_perform", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error:

> Cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::__1::basic_string<char>' through variadic function; call will abort at runtime

On this line:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=" + *i);
```

because of the `+ *i`.

Is what I want to do possible? Is there a solution?

EDIT: Thanks for the answer, but for some reason, when I run this it only gets the website with the last string in the vector, and it ignores the other ones. In my case, it skips `James` and goes straight to `Andrew`. Why does that happen?

Comment: Make a `std::string`, then use `c_str()` to get a C-style string pointer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parameter passed to `curl_easy_setopt` for `CURLOPT_URL` needs to be a `char *` instead of a `std::string`. You can get a `const char *` from a `std::string` by calling its `c_str` member function:

```
std::string url = "http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=" + *i;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

For anyone who ends up here in the future, take a look at the [curl manual](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c) if you haven't already. There's also an [online book](https://ec.haxx.se).

The documentation for [curl_easy_setopt](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) says you need to read about a specific option to know what parameter type to use.

> All options are set with an option followed by a parameter. That parameter can be a long, a function pointer, an object pointer or a curl_off_t, **depending on what the specific option expects. Read this manual carefully** as bad input values may cause libcurl to behave badly!

The documentation for [CURLOPT_URL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) says exactly what the parameter type needs to be.

> Pass in a pointer to the URL to work with. **The parameter should be a char * to a zero terminated string** which must be URL-encoded in the following format:
>
> scheme://host:port/path

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason, when I run this it only gets the website with the last string in the vector, and it ignores the other ones. In my case, it skips `James` and goes straight to `Andrew`. Why does that happen?

You are looping through all of the names configuring the `curl` object with a different name on each loop iteration, THEN you are calling `curl_easy_perform()` only after the loop has finished, so it will retrieve only the last name that was configured.  You need to move your call to `curl_easy_perform()` inside of the loop instead:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = names.begin(); i != names.end(); ++i)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, long(m_timeout));

    string url = "http://foo.com/foo.asp?name=" + *i;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1L);

    success = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (success != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "curl_easy_perform", errbuf);
        // handle the error as needed...
        continue;
    }

    // use the downloaded content as needed...
}
```