# can we pass wstring in CURLOPT_URL

Tags: libcurl, wstring

I tried passing wstring url but it is failing,
is there any correct way to pass it or 
can we pass wstring encoded url in CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_URL, ?)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/23721344/1072229

Comment: Thanks Daniel, my mistake in docs it is given that, 

Pass in a pointer to the URL to work with. The parameter should be a char * to a zero terminated string which must be URL-encoded in the following format:
scheme://host:port/path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. [CURLOPT_URL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) takes a C string as input.