# libcurl returns error 3: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL when using std::string variable

Tags: c++, get, libcurl

I'm using libcurl and following the simple [https GET tutorial](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html) from the libcurl website.

When I hardcode the website URL when setting the CURLOPT_URL option, the request works:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if (CURLE_OK != result)
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "HTTP REQ failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(result));
}
```

However, when I put the URL into a std::string and then use the string as the input, it no longer works:

```
std::string url("https://www.google.com/");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if (CURLE_OK != result)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "HTTP REQ failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(result));
}
```

The request then returns with an error code of 3 (`CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT`) and the error says:

> URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

**What am I missing here for it to work when I directly hardcode the URL but not work when I use a std::string?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23721344/451600

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Curl is a C library. It expects C strings (`const char *`) *not* C++ `std::string` objects.

You want `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());`